# Area bounded by two circles $x^2 + y^2 = 1, x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1$

Tags: calculus

Consider the area enclosed by two circles: $x^2 + y^2 = 1, x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1$
Calculate this area using double integrals:

I think I have determined the region to be $D = \{(x,y)| 0 \leq y \leq 1, \sqrt{1-y^2} \leq x \leq \sqrt{1 - (1-y)^2}\}$

Now I can't seem to integrate this. Is this region wrong? Should the integral just be $\int_0^1 \int_{\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1- (1-y)^2}} dx dy$?

Do I need to convert this to polar form?

Comment: I swear to god I saw this exact same question before

Comment: @JChau Just ran a few searches and couldn't find it, can you possibly comment in a link? Do you remember the answer?

Comment: Must have been a dream or something... Your username looks familiar from *that* question as well... Huh idk why

Comment: Yep I was going crazy srry

Comment: @JChau It is a pretty good looking username, I get that alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a picture. You will note that part of the region is in the second quadrant.

If you want to use rectangular coordinates, it will be necessary to see where circles meet. That is not at $x=1$. If we solve the system of two equations, pretty quickly we get $y=\frac{1}{2}$, which gives $x=\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Your integral setup would be almost right if you had integrated from $x=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ to $x=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. The $y$ should range from $1-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ to $\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

However, it might be preferable to take advantage of the symmetry and integrate from $x=0$ to $x=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, and double the result.

But as you indicated, polar may be better. The two circles have polar equations $r=1$ and $r=2\sin\theta$. The curves meet where $2\sin\theta=1$, so in the first quadrant at $r=1$, $\theta=\frac{\pi}{6}$ and also at $r=1$, $\theta=\frac{5\pi}{6}$.

Let's find the first quadrant area and double. Up to $\frac{\pi}{6}$, our bounding curve is $r=2\sin\theta$, and then up to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ it is $r=1$. So half our area is 
$$\int_0^{\pi/6} 2r\sin\theta \,dr\,d\theta+\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/2}r\,dr\,d\theta.$$
(The second integral could be replaced by a simple geometric argument.)

**Added:** For the first integral, integrate first with respect to $r$. We get $\sin\theta$. Then integrate with respect to $\theta$. We get $1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

The second integral gives the area of a circular sector with angle $\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{6}$, which is $\frac{\pi}{3}$, one-sixth of a circle, so area $\frac{\pi}{6}$. Thus **half** our area is $1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{\pi}{6}$.

Comment: (if you computed it) what answer did you obtain?

Comment: The (full) area is $2-\sqrt{3}+\frac{\pi}{3}$.

Comment: There is probably no way you could know this, but I got $\frac{2\pi}{3} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ any ideas why? (asking because this obviously differs from your answer)

Comment: I had a typo in the original formula. My guess about the $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ is that when you were integrating $\sin\theta$ and got $-\cos\theta$, and needed to plug in $\pi/6$ and take away the result of plugging in $0$, you assumed $\cos 0=0$, and it is $1$.

Comment: Unrelated minor question(Don't think it deserves an entire question), is the Jacobian when converting $ dx \cdot dy $ to $ r\cdot dr \cdot d\theta$ the same when converting $dy \cdot dx$ ? So does it also equal $r \cdot dr \cdot d\theta$?

Comment: Yes, the Jacobian in each case is $r$.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are always very helpful!

Comment: You are welcome. That is what the site is about.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the system: $x^2 + y^2 = 1 = x^2 + (y - 1)^2$ we have: $x =\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $y = \dfrac{1}{2}$, and $x = -\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $y = \dfrac{1}{2}$. So the set up for the integral is:$\int_\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}} \int_{1 -\sqrt{1 - x^2}}^{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} 1dydx$ which can be easily computed.

Comment: That was the first integral I obtained, but it seems that region is even more difficult to 'easily compute'. How would I go about integrating this?

Comment: @DisplayName: you look up the table of integral for anti-derivative of $\sqrt{1 - x^2$

Comment: (if you computed it) what answer did you obtain?

Answer (score 1):

(I recognize you asked for a method using double integrals; I'm leaving this here as "extra")

Using geometry, the area we want is the area of four one-sixth sectors of a circle with $r = 1$ subtracted by the area of two equilateral triangles of side length $s = 1$. This would be

$$ \frac{2}{3} \pi (1)^2 - 2 \frac{(1)^2 \sqrt{3}}{4} = \frac{2}{3} \pi - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$